# Changes made to member of object, inside object, inside a vector, do not survive end of method. C++

Tags: c++, c++11, object, vector

Sorry for the title. I cannot made something more descriptive or clear than that..

I'm trying to do something that resembles a very basic auction.

To simplify things, I'm going to put here the essentials of every class.
I'm also translated everything from spanish to english, so if there is a typo, it's only here. The actual code compile fine.

There are four classes involved here:

```
class Person
{
private:
    std::string name;
}

class Offer
{
private:
    int amount;
    Person *bidder;
}

class Item
{
private:
    int itemNumber;
    std::string itemName;
    Offer *biggestBidder;

public:
    Item(int, std::string)
    void setbiggestBidder(Offer* const &); // I did this '* const &' thing while trying solutions
    Oferta *getBiggestBidder();
}

class Auction
{
private:
    std::vector<Item> itemCollection;
    int amountOfItems; // in above's collection 
}
```

I didn't put the getters, setters, and constructors/destructors here so it's not too long.
Inside Item.cpp I have:

```
Item::Item(int number, std::string name)
:itemNumber(number), 
itemName(name), 
biggestBidder(NULL)
{
    // this->itemNumber= number;
    // this->itemName= name;
    // this->biggestBidder= NULL;
}

void Item::setbiggestBidder(Offer* const &offer)
{
    if (biggestBidder== NULL || biggestBidder->getAmount() < offer->getAmount())
    {
        std::cout << "Address of offer in setbiggestBidder: " << offer << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: " << (biggestBidder) << std::endl;
        biggestBidder = offer;
        std::cout << "Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: " << (biggestBidder) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

Oferta *Lote::getBiggestBidder()
{

    std::cout << "Address of biggestBidder in getBiggestBidder(): " << this->biggestBidder << std::endl;
    if (this->biggestBidder == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "biggestBidder IS NULL" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "biggestBidder is NOT NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    return biggestBidder;
}
```

Now, the main and the problem:

```
Item l1(111, "BANANA");
Item l2(222, "MESA"); // this number 222 is just an ID for the item. It does nothing
Person p1("TheDude");
Offer of1(100, &p1);

// now put the item inside a vector and create an auction instance
std::vector<Item> item1;
collect.push_back(banana);
Auction coleccion1(collect, collect.size());


/*
Now we are ready. If I do this..
*/

std::cout << "Test with item outside vector" << std::endl;

std::cout << "Bidding $" << of1.getAmount() << " for item number " 
            << l2.getNumber() << ", " << l2.getItemName() << std::endl;

l2.setBiggestBidder(&of1); // amount 100
/*
If here I do 

l2.setBiggestBidder(&of2); // amount 200
l2.setBiggestBidder(&of1); // amount 100

At the bottom of the output, we get 200. It's all good.
*/
std::cout << l2.getBiggestBidder()->getAmount() << std::endl;

/* 
We get this output:
Test with item outside vector
Bidding $100 for item number 222, MESA
Address of offer in setbiggestBidder: 0x66fb20
Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: 0
Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: 0x66fb20
Address of biggestBidder in getBiggestBidder(): 0x66fb20
biggestBidder is NOT NULL
200 <-- l2.getBiggestBidder()->getAmount()
*/

// But if we try with the item inside the vector:

std::cout << "Bidding $" << of1.getAmount() << " for item number " 
                << coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0).getNumber() << ", " 
                    << coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0).getItemName() << std::endl;

/*
We get:
Test with item in vector
Bidding $100 for item number 111, BANANA
Address of offer in setbiggestBidder: 0x66fb10
Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: 0
Address of biggestBidder in setbiggestBidder: 0x66fb10
Address of biggestBidder in getBiggestBidder(): 0
biggestBidder IS NULL
0

and here is the issue.
*/
```

I really do not like having to do a post so large for a problem that I'm sure is about something extremely basic, but I have looked everywhere and cannot find any solution to this problem.
It have been weeks since I stumbled upon this.

Why is that everything works fine if I put an item on the method setBiggestBidder, but the change does not survive the end of the method when I put an item that is inside of a vector? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where do you call `setBiggestBidder` on `coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0)`? What is `banana`?

Comment: Are you aware that `collect.push_back(l2);` creates a copy? Every change to `l2` is not applied to `coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0)`.

Comment: You have two different objects that you're updating. You update the mesa but then expect the changes on the banana? Even if you were trying to update the same item, as mentioned above, you'd be putting a copy into the vector. I think you need to spent a bit more time on crafting the question to the exact issue you have having.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I was not aware of that. And thanks to you, I was able to solve it. In the Auction class, I changed std::vector<Item> for std::vector<Item*> and that did the trick. Thanks man!

Comment: @Taekahn No. You are mixing the two examples. One showing how the code works with one item, and the other one showing was happens when the item is inside a vector (where I had the problem). Of course I don't want to modify mesa when working with banana.. It was just a basic thing, as I thought. I just didn't knew that vector created a copy.
Now, how do I proceed with the post? If needed, I can update it with the complete code to replicate the error and then the solution. But it would be a very large post for a basic isse.

Comment: You should remove it or create a [mcve]. A minimal example would be about 10 lines of code. It contains a main function, a vector and an object or primitive value. You can reproduce the problem with integers. You don't need the classes. Please don't post your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

`collect.push_back(l2);` creates a copy. `l2` and `coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0)` are two different objects. If you change `l2` `coleccion1.getItemCollection().at(0)` won't be changed. You could store a pointer in the vector. You should remember that the object is destroyed at the end of the function and the vector contains a dangling pointer.